# SoftHSM2 return "Error parsing configuration"

Tags: softhsm

I'm trying to use Softhsm2 in my project. Unfortunately, it keeps showing

> java.security.ProviderException: Error parsing configuration

I try reinstall the app but problem still remain. May I know what I missed? Please check below source code, config file, tokens, java version & environment variable.

[error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WodYa.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
         String configName = "softhsm2.conf";

         Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);
         
         if (-1 == Security.addProvider(p)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("could not add security provider");
         }

         // Load the key store
         char[] pin = "mypin".toCharArray();
         KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
         keyStore.load(null, pin);

         // AES key
         SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(), "AES");
         Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeySpec.getEncoded(), "AES");

         keyStore.setKeyEntry("AA", key, "1234".toCharArray(), null);
         keyStore.store(null); //this gives me the exception.                             
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Token generated:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1304]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd/

C:\>cd softhsm2

C:\SoftHSM2>cd bin

C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
Available slots:
Slot 1759353984
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x68dd9c80
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:    8414edde68dd9c80
        Initialized:      yes
        User PIN init.:   yes
        Label:            My token 2
Slot 2066642166
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x7b2e74f6
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:    9176dec57b2e74f6
        Initialized:      yes
        User PIN init.:   yes
        Label:            My token 1
Slot 2
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x2
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:
        Initialized:      no
        User PIN init.:   no
        Label:

C:\SoftHSM2\bin>
```

Config: C:\SoftHSM2\etc\softhsm2.conf

```
# SoftHSM v2 configuration file
directories.tokendir = C:\SoftHSM2\var\softhsm2\tokens\
objectstore.backend = file
log.level = INFO
slots.removable = false
```

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Environment variable
SOFTHSM2_CONF C:\SoftHSM2\etc\softhsm2.conf

Path: C:\SoftHSM2\lib\

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JAVA expert but you seem to be passing incorrect configuration to `SunPKCS11` provider.

There seem to be two different configurations in your scenario:

1. **`SunPKCS11` configuration** that instructs `SunPKCS11` provider which PKCS#11 library to load.
2. **`SoftHSM2` configuration** that instructs `SoftHSM2` library where to store data etc.

[`SunPKCS11` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html#GUID-C4ABFACB-B2C9-4E71-A313-79F881488BB9) suggests that in your case `SunPKCS11` configuration should look similar to this:

```
name = SofHSM2
library = c:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll
```